# generate a set of of all combinations of special characters and numbers around a string - python

Tags: python, combinations, permutation

I am attempting to generate all combinations of special characters and numbers around a string.  For example, suppose the string is 'notebook' and the special characters are @, #, $, %, & and numbers 0-9.  This could generate:  $#notebook12, notebook8, @5notebook0&.  I am assuming no repeats of characters.

Thanks in advance.

So far I can only generate:

```
special = ['@','#','$','%','&',' ',0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,' ']

choice = list(permutations(special, 2))
word = ['notebook']

pw_choice = word + choice
test = list(permutations(pw_choice, 2))

print(test)
```

But this results in a list of list that I would have to manipulate further.  Is there an easier work around to produce the set of _ _ notebook _ _ ?

Comment: How many characters are you allowing before and after the chosen word? You seem to imply 2 before and after, but your example of "notebook8" only has 1 after and maybe none (or 1 if it is a space) before?

Comment: Iterate over the list of permutations in pairs and use string formatting to construct a string using each pair as a prefix and suffix.

Comment: @JohnFrum at most 2 before and after the chose word.  so it can be 'notebook8' or '8notebook' or '91notebook8' or ' 8notebook91' etc.

Comment: Is `'@ word'` valid?

Comment: @wwii '@ word' is not valid, i apologize for not noting that.  the only absence of a character should be at the beginning or end i.e. ' @word@ '

Comment: I think that this means that ' ' should not be in the list of special characters, as it seems to be being used to indicate that there is no chosen character, but that just means we have, say, 1 before and/or after instead of 2.

Comment: @JohnFrum correct - i shouldn't use the ' ' in the list because this would generate the cases of '@ word $' with spaces in between - thank you for the heads up.

Comment: What exactly is your question - `how to add prefix and suffix to a string?` or `how to generate combinations 1 or two at a time?` or `how to iterate over a list?` or ???

Comment: @wii how can i generate the entire set of words  that have combinations of prefix and suffixes from the special characters i.e. '39notebook', '$notebook', ...

Comment: I've just added some logic pls, Check @tycho-bro-hey

Comment: @tycho-bro-hey Please look at my second approach as well :)

Comment: Can a special character be used twice? Is `'@word@'`  or `'@@word'` valid?

Comment: @wwii single use of special characters and numbers

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
from itertools import combinations, permutations

result = [
    ''.join(p)
    for n_chars in range(len(special) + 1)
    for chars in combinations(special, n_chars)
    for p in permutations(('notebook',) + chars)
]
```

Example with `special = ['@','#','$']`:

```
['notebook', 'notebook@', '@notebook', 'notebook#', '#notebook',
 'notebook$', '$notebook', 'notebook@#', 'notebook#@',
 '@notebook#', '@#notebook', '#notebook@', '#@notebook',
 'notebook@$', 'notebook$@', '@notebook$', '@$notebook',
 '$notebook@', '$@notebook', 'notebook#$', 'notebook$#',
 '#notebook$', '#$notebook', '$notebook#', '$#notebook',
 'notebook@#$', 'notebook@$#', 'notebook#@$', 'notebook#$@',
 'notebook$@#', 'notebook$#@', '@notebook#$', '@notebook$#',
 '@#notebook$', '@#$notebook', '@$notebook#', '@$#notebook',
 '#notebook@$', '#notebook$@', '#@notebook$', '#@$notebook',
 '#$notebook@', '#$@notebook', '$notebook@#', '$notebook#@',
 '$@notebook#', '$@#notebook', '$#notebook@', '$#@notebook']
```

If you only want at most two chars before and after the "notebook" string:

```
from itertools import combinations

result = [
    f'{"{}"*b}notebook{"{}"*a}'.format(*c)
    for b in range(3)
    for a in range(3)
    for c in combinations(special, a + b)
]
```

This is the result (with `special = ['@','#','$']`):

```
['notebook', 'notebook@', 'notebook#', 'notebook$', 'notebook@#',
 'notebook@$', 'notebook#$', '@notebook', '#notebook', '$notebook',
 '@notebook#', '@notebook$', '#notebook$', '@notebook#$',
 '@#notebook', '@$notebook', '#$notebook', '@#notebook$']
```

Comment: This does produce all the combinations but with more than the requested maximum of 2 before and after the word.

Comment: thank you Riccardo, it does produce a bit more than i need but i believe i can make the necessary changes.

Answer (score 2):

Based on your comment: "*at most 2 before and after the chose word*", you only have 7 templates. I categorized those in a tuple in advance and format them in for loop later.

- The outer loop is there to generate `r`s for the `permutations`.

```py
from itertools import permutations
from time import sleep


def generate_word(word: str):
    numbers_and_symbols = list("0123456789") + list("@#$%&")

    templates = (
        (f"{{}}{word}", f"{word}{{}}"),                            # 1 item
        (f"{{}}{word}{{}}", f"{word}{{}}{{}}", f"{{}}{{}}{word}"), # 2 items
        (f"{{}}{{}}{word}{{}}", f"{{}}{word}{{}}{{}}"),            # 3 items
        (f"{{}}{{}}{word}{{}}{{}}",),                               # 4 items
    )

    for i in range(1, 5):
        for t in permutations(numbers_and_symbols, r=i):
            for string in templates[i-1]:
                yield string.format(*t)
                sleep(0.05)


for i in generate_word("notebook"):
    print(i)
```

I've added sleep so that you can see what is generated.

Comment: thank you, i will try this in one moment!

Comment: `list("@#$ %&")` --> `list("@#$%&")` ? From the comments - ` '@ word' is not valid`

Answer (score 2):

Same thing but different - long form.

```
import itertools

q = ['@', '#', '$', '%', '&',0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
word = 'notebook'
results = []
# one at a time
for c in q:
    results.append(f'{c}{word}')
    results.append(f'{word}{c}')

for a,b in itertools.combinations(q,2):
    results.append(f'{a}{b}{word}')
    results.append(f'{word}{a}{b}')
    results.append(f'{a}{word}{b}')
    
for a,b,c in itertools.combinations(q,3):
    results.append(f'{a}{b}{word}{c}')
    results.append(f'{a}{word}{b}{c}')

for a,b,c,d in itertools.combinations(q,4):
    results.append(f'{a}{b}{word}{c}{d}')
```

---

Not very flexible; I like [Ricardo Bucco's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74537305/2823755).

Answer (score 1):

Simply select 4 random unique elemnts from main list & Inject uisng fstrings.

```
import itertools
special = ['@','#','$','%','&',' ',0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,' ']
lis=[]

word = ['notebook']
word = ''.join(word)


for comb in itertools.combinations(special, 4):
    first = str(comb[0])+str(comb[1])
    last = str(comb[2])+str(comb[3])

   
    final =f'{first}{word}{last}'
    if final.startswith("@"):
        pass
    else:
        
        lis.append(final)


print(lis)
```

some sample outputs #

> ['#$notebook%&', '#$notebook% ', '#$notebook%0', '#$notebook%1',
> '#$notebook%2', '#$notebook%3', '#$notebook%4', '#$notebook%5',
> '#$notebook%6', '#$notebook%7', '#$notebook%8', '#$notebook%9',
> '#$notebook% ', '#$notebook& ', '#$notebook&0', '#$notebook&1',
> '#$notebook&2', '#$notebook&3', '#$notebook&4', '#$notebook&5',,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,

In this case Produced

```
2380 combination
```

If we ignore starts with `@` produces.

```
1820 combination
```

Comment: Is it possible to produce `'@ word'`? Would that meet the spec?

Comment: Yes, Updated...